# Inject HTML into iframe across domain

Tags: iframe

In the html, there's one iframe loading external page from different domain. And I cant change the source code of this external page.

Now I want to inject some html codes into the iframe, such as adding one link in the external page.

What's the possible way for me to do that?

I tried to use contentWindow.document, but getting permission issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible. however if you want to do this at any cost, you can download the required page using server side like  file_get_contents('http://www.google.com'); in php. and make changes to it, save it in a file on your server and then open it in iframe you want to.

Comment: I don't think it meets the requirement. Since it's a complete website not just one page.